Powering a Raspberry Pi 5 using a phone charger with a normal output of 5.0V 3.0A 15.0W, and fast output of 5.0-20.0V 6.2-3.25A 67W max
Is it safe, and will the Raspberry Pi 5 function properly?

Yes, it is safe in the sense it should not physically damage the Pi, however, as per the duplicate question the amperage may be insufficient (so may not work, or cause the system to shut off when under stress, which can lead to data corruption etc).
